# Adding multiple values to MySQL inside a loop

Tags: python, mysql

I scrape a list of elements from the site and extract two values from it. The `text` and the `href`. I cannot figure out how to add these to the `mysql` DB in side a loop. I tried `execute` inside the loop, without using the list they are appeneded to, that failed. So, I tried `executemany` but I think my format might be incorrect. I saw examples where a list of tuples is fed to `executemany`, I don't know how to do that in this case.

```
                for name in name_eles:
                    names_list.append(name.text)
                    n_li = name.get_attribute('href')
                    names_links.append(n_li)
                sql = "INSERT INTO profiles(company, coprofile) VALUES (%s,%s)"
                val = [(name for name in name_list),(n_li for n_li in names_links)]
                cursor.executemany(sql,val)
```

This is the error I get.

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

Comment: va1 = (myvar1,myvar2) under loop of lists

Comment: That's what I tried before. I will run it again and confirm.

Comment: sorry didn't see executemany,you can do it within a lists loop and the above method,are both lists the same len?

Comment: @AbhishekRai Are you able to solve it using a list of tuples? trying printing your val and the val in my answer to get the difference between both of them.

Comment: @KaushalSharma No, It doesn't work with `executemany`. I was just verifying that the data incoming is correct. It is. However, it doesn't write it.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Are you executing `commit` after `executemany`?

Comment: `autocommit` is set to `True`. It writes the data captured before this in the code anyways. It is not giving any error...but, so I don't know what to solve.

Comment: @KaushalSharma It writes only the first element of the list. Then there are 6 blank rows, though the number of rows is 38, because I am writing the same to a text file as well.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Can you provide some kind of logs or maybe values of `name_list`, `names_links`.  And any error you are getting, also try to do it in a `for loop` using `execute` instead of `executemany`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230043/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-kaushal-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a `list` of `tuples` in the `executemany` arguments.

You can simply try this:

```
val = list(zip(name_list, names_links))
```

You can read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)